# issus with emoji in array

Tags: php, arrays, emoji

In this code, when I use ":-)" emoji doesn't show in output.

But when use "1f60a" OR "1f60c" OR "e252" emoji are shown. What's the problem?

```
<?php
    $emoji_url = "http://coremobile.ir/images_smileys";
    $emoji_style = "";
    $emoji_code = array(
        ":-)",
        "1f60a",
        "1f60c",
        "e252"
    );

    $emoji_img = array(
        '<img src="'.$emoji_url.'/1f60a.png" '.$emoji_style.'>',
        '<img src="'.$emoji_url.'/1f60a.png" '.$emoji_style.'>',
        '<img src="'.$emoji_url.'/1f60c.png" '.$emoji_style.'>',
        '<img src="'.$emoji_url.'/e252.png" '.$emoji_style.'>'
    );

    $ret = 'This Test :-)  1f60a';
    $ret = str_replace($emoji_code, $emoji_img, $ret);
    echo $ret;
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$ret` in the end?

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

(Just use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) instead of [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), so that it won't go through the string multiple times)

```
$ret = strtr($ret, array_combine($emoji_code, $emoji_img));
```

output:

> This Test [image][image]

The otherone didn't worked, because it replaced every match for the first replacement and then the second and so on.

0 replaced:

```
This Test :-)  1f60a
        //^^^ match
```

first replaced:

```
This Test <img src="http://coremobile.ir/images_smileys/1f60a.png" > 1f60a
                                                      //^^^^^ match  ^^^^^ match
```

second replaced:

```
This Test <img src="http://coremobile.ir/images_smileys/<img src="http://coremobile.ir/images_smileys/1f60a.png" >.png" >  <img src="http://coremobile.ir/images_smileys/1f60a.png" >
```